# omxplayer ignores --fps option when playing h264 file

Tags: omxplayer, h264

I made a video using the Raspberry Pi camera that came with a .h264 extension. I know that this file doesn't have the fps metadata associated with it. I found that playing it with omxplayer like this:

```
omxplayer myvideo.h264
```

resulted in highly accelerated fps, a 10 second video was played in 1 or 2 seconds. After adding the --fps option the result is the same:

```
omxplayer --fps 30 myvideo.h264
```

I also tried with:

```
omxplayer myvideo.h264 --fps 30
```

My omxplayer version:

```
$ omxplayer --version
omxplayer - Commandline multimedia player for the Raspberry Pi
        Build date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 00:56:49 +0000
        Version   : dfea8c9 [master]
        Repository: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer.git
```

I don't want to convert the h264 to mp4. I want to store the h264 file in a USB flash drive and play it from there to an HDMI screen. The files will have up to 5-6 hours of video and I don't want to lose time converting them automatically to mp4 after the recording and, more importantly, I don't want to have to get a storage medium that is double of that necessary to store the data just to be able to check the recording locally on the device itself using the included display.

I tried VLC with no success also, but on VLC I couldn't even display a video on the screen.

Comment: Running the video past ffmpeg may provide useful information... `ffmpeg -i myvideo.h264`  should give you the codec information.  You can do it right from the Pi if you have ffmpeg installed, or transfer the video to a PC and check there... if that's easier for you.